# Sweetalert промисы и masked input

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

Задача такая:

Необходимо, чтобы в sweetalert окне появился input с определенной маской вводимых данных (jQuery MaskedInput), а далее, после получения данных отправить Ajax.

Я пробовал реализовать это с помощью свойства "content" у окошка Sweetalert, но не понял, как в таком случае к input подключить маску:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#kvm-table .timemore', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      kvmid = $(this).data('kvm');
      console.log(kvmid);
      swal({
        text: "На какое время продлить",
        content: {
          element: "input",    // Как подключить маску для этого input?? 
          attributes: {
            name: "timemore",
         },
        },
      }).then((timemore) => {
          // тут Ajax
          },
        });

          
      });
  });
```

Тогда в голову пришла другая идея - просто вставлять готовый input в окошко, но тут не совсем понятно как после этого отправлять данные (кроме как банальной обработкой клика окошка):

```
    $(document).on('click', '#kvm-table .timemore', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      kvmid = $(this).data('kvm');
      console.log(kvmid);
      swal({
        text: "На какое время продлить",
        content: {
          element: "div"
        },
      });

      $('<input class="swal-content__input" name="timemore" type="text">')
    .mask("99:99").appendTo('.swal-content');

  });
```

Чувствую, если допилю второй вариант - получится костыль тупо из-за незнания промисов. Как думаете, как реализовать данный код правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю библиотеку sweet alert и моё решение может выглядеть костылём, но я не нашёл ничего другого, как заранее создавать элемент:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  let mask = "+7(999) 999-9999";
  let $inp = $("<input/>").attr({
    type: 'text',
    placeholder: mask
  }).mask(mask);

  $('#test-button').click(function(e) {
    swal({
      text: "Введите номер телефона",
      buttons: true,
      content: {
        element: $inp[0]
      }
    })
    .then((value) => {
      let phoneNumber = $.trim($inp.val());
      if(value && !!phoneNumber) {
        swal('Выбранный номер: ' + phoneNumber);
      }
      else {
        swal('Печалька :(')
        .then((value) => $('#test-button').click());
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.maskedinput@1.4.1/src/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<button id="test-button">Click me</button>
```

Обратите внимание, что в content.element передаётся не jQuery объект, а HTML-Node: `$inp[0]`.
Поиграться можно [здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/XelaNimed/o4yxb7jd/).

Comment: Спасибо. Простое и понятное решение. Что самое интересное - и его пробовал только в content сцвал не $inp[0] а весь $inp. Поэтому не работало)